# Devise admin model not able to complete session controller functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building a basic CRUD application. The user model is working perfectly. However, I created my second devise model (admin) and I am receiving an error when trying to sign_in and sign_out with my admin account.

**The Error**

```
uninitialized constant Admins::SessionsControllerController
```

**sessions_controllers.rb**

The admin controller is in controllers/admins/sessions_controllers.rb

```
class Admins::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :gifts
devise_for :users
devise_for :admins, :controllers => { :sessions => "admins/sessions_controller" }

authenticated :user do
  root to: "gifts#index", :as => "authenticated_user_root" 
end

authenticated :admin do
  root to: "management#index", :as => "authenticated_admin_root" 
end

root :to => 'pages#index'
```

I also see the proper route coming up when I rake routes:

```
destroy_user_session_path    DELETE  /users/sign_out(.:format)   devise/sessions#destroy
```

**admin.rb**

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

**Full trace**

```
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `const_get'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `block in constantize'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `each'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `inject'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `constantize'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `controller_reference'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `controller'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:44:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:44:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
```

I'm looking for help to get my admin model working properly. Does anyone know how to get this working properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the devise_for,

```
devise_for :admins, :controllers => { :sessions => "admins/sessions_controller" }
```

it should be

```
devise_for :admins, :controllers => { :sessions => "admins/sessions" }
```

See https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers